# Load different view controllers from the object selected from TableView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5

I need some assistance to approach this. I have created a `UITabBarController` where I have two tabs. And in one of them I made it to pop with `UIPopoverController` where I use a `UITableView` inside the `UIPopoverController`. I load the tableView with two objects using table view datasource and I can see them when the `UIPopoverController` appears.

You can check the screen shot here:

[image: Screenshot]

Now what I want to achieve is that, when I click on feedback then I need to be directed/taken to `feedbackViewController` and the same with the other object Download, it should take me to the `downloadViewController`.

I know that I need to use table view method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

But I am not having an idea of how I can do this. So any general information of how I can approach this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds quite simple. All you need to do is identify which button was pressed, in this case 0 for Feedback and 1 for Download. Then depending on that present the appropriate view controller.
You will probably need to have a link to a parent, which will ultimately present the new view. Otherwise you will be presenting the view inside the popover controller.

Somewhere when creating/displaying your `UIPopoverController` create a reference to the parent

```
UIViewController *mainparent = _mainparent; //where _mainparent is the reference passed through.
```

Then in your `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` include the following.

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
    [mainparent presentModalViewController:feedbackViewController animated:YES];
else
    [mainparent presentModalViewController:downloadViewController animated:YES];
```

That will modally present the required view controllers.

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for your reply. I have few questions regarding this. What do you mean by reference to the parent. In my design I am creating the UIViewControllers and handling them using AppDelegate.m using - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions. I created FirstViewController (webview), SecondViewController (where I pop up the popovercontroller with tableview) and a popovercontroller. Now which would be the parent controller in my case. Bear me for my naive, Im getting into IOS. Thanks

Comment: One more info, I created a Empty Application using xcode 4.2.1 and from there I added all the required view controllers

Comment: The parent would be which ever viewcontroller you want to replace. So I think it might be your `firstViewControler`, but depending on your application, you might want to be replacing you secondviewcontroller.

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks once again for your answer that worked. I have got another strange problem. In my feedbackViewController I cannot find the tabBarController with tabs any more. Even if I switch back to FirstViewController using a backButton, even in the FVC the tabBar items are vanishing. Could you let me know how to fix this. Thanks for your replies dude.

Comment: No problem. Would you mind accepting if this works?. It depends on how you've organised the tab bar, what you should be doing is having the tab bar as the main view, then the viewcontroller it is displaying should be changed, maybe using the `UINavigationController`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Amit, are you still active in this, I have got a couple of questions. In case if you are still available just leave me an answer, I will post my questions

Comment: I can be. Would be useful if you could accept this answer however.

Comment: Hi Amit, I am sorry that I forgot to accept your answer. Thanks mate. Now I accepted it. Are you available on chat or skype, so that I can share my screen in case if you want to go through it. Saves lots of time for both.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the time to help like that. Your best bet would be to post questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: ok no probs, I followed your create a reference to the parent using UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil]; in the PopOverViewController.m file inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Now when I use if (indexPath.row == 0)
    [viewController2 presentModalViewController:feedbackViewController animated:YES];
else
    [viewController2 presentModalViewController:downloadViewController animated:YES]; it is not taking me to the concerned views. Instead if I use self instead of viewController2, I am taken to views

Comment: That is probably because you're using modal view controllers, which is fine, I wasn't sure if it would just present the viewcontroller in your popup, or in the whole app.

Comment: but on the other hand as I said my tabBarController is vanishing in this new views(feedBack, downLoad). In my AppDelegate.m file Im doing this inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions{self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, tableView3 ,nil];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];}. What am I doing wrong? In case if you need more info please let me know, will provide

Comment: I want to present the view in the whole app with TabBar intact at the bottom of the feedBack/downLoad views

Comment: Try something like a UINavigationController in your parentview, and use parentview.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:myviewcontroller];

Comment: Hi Amit, can you provide a general example with a basic code. I think i am lost. Thanks

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077613/uinavigationcontroller-simplest-example