# View Based app issue when loading a UITableView (.xib)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, view

My app is a ViewBased app. I added a subclass of type UITableView with its .xib
when i press a button i want to load the UITableView xib but it loads only the table with no Navigation bar and search bar i added.
Here's the code to load the view:

```
- (IBAction)changeView:(id)sender;
{
   TableViewController *tableview =[[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil   bundle:nil];
   [self presentModalViewController:tableview animated:YES];
}
```

This is what I want to load:

[image 1 http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/3846/wantf.png](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/3846/wantf.png)

and this is what it loads:

[image 2 http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/9928/loadu.png](http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/9928/loadu.png)

How can I solve the issue and load the view with nav and search bar ?
Thanks in advance mates.

Comment: If you have NIB file then why dont you pass the NIB name while initializing , but you are passing nil. pass the name of the XIB file which you have created in [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController"   bundle:nil];

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your view controller in a UINavigationController, like this:

[UINavigationController: Simplest Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077613/uinavigationcontroller-simplest-example)

So try this:

```
   TableViewController *tableview =[[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil   bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableview]; 
   [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Comment: can u explain me please what exactly i have to do ?
i go on my .xib and add a UINavigationController and ?

Comment: Thanks mate... Works fine now but can't see the search bar too :(

Answer (score 0):

When editing your xib file, I believe XCode gives you the option of showing/hiding your search bar.