# Uiwebview link in new navigation and webview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview, hyperlink, uiwebview

I'm developing an application. In this application I have a webview. I need to open webview links in a new webview, because I need to add back a botton in navigation. I searched about this on Stack Overflow, but I did not find anything. How can I do this?

I'm new to [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) development.

---- update -----

I have to use UINavigationController ,but i need to open webview1 links in webview2 . webview2 is in new webview in new viewController. because i need back botton. please check [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/axyqti5kejyd8yg/%5B%E8%8B%B9%E6%9E%9C%E5%BD%95%E5%B1%8F%E5%A4%A7%E5%B8%88%5D%5B2014-10-3-18-42-45%5D%5B480x720%5D.mp4?dl=0) video.

when i touch a app its goes to new view controller and it have back bottom. my idea is it. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your goals I think you need to use UINavigationController. But I still think that it's bad decision. Anyway if you need navigate between controllers use UINavigationController. How to do that you can find [here](http://bharanijayasuri.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/simple-uinavigationcontroller-tutorial-2/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077613/uinavigationcontroller-simplest-example) and [here](http://www.ralfebert.de/archive/ios/tutorial_iosdev/navigationcontroller/).

Comment: please check next answer

Answer (score 0):

If you embedded you fist webviewcontroller in navigation controller and then implement push to second controller you'll see back button in navigation bar. Of course if it isn't hidden.

```
 UIViewController *cont=[[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

 self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:cont];
```

On webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:

```
 UIViewController *secondVC=[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 secondVC.webView loadRequest:request];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm new to Xcode. Please Explain in simple. I don't understand. Sorry .

Comment: I created a little demo project here - https://github.com/okulak/OpenLinkInNewController. You can find there how it's works.  Just set your URLs. Don't forget setup special link for check.

Comment: what is special link? how can i setup this ? can i have your email ?

Comment: In first webview set page adress with link, specil link - your link to another page. It's just check for specific link. Otherwise new view controller will open on any request.
If you still have questions you can contact me on my email - mr.alexbest@gmail.com =)